# How can we use session value in trigger in SQL Server 2012 and insert into a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

How can we use session value in trigger in SQL Server 2012 and insert into a table?
I created a session but getting confuse, how can i use session value into a trigger.
I'm creating a log table for view all logs that which action is acted in main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are database object which is bound to a table and is executed automatically. You can’t explicitly invoke triggers. The only way to do this is by performing the required action on the table that they are assigned to.

So In Case you wish to save your session value ,Save it in the Table on  which trigger is created and then save it in Log Table .

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @SessionValue varchar(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
    select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
    select @SessionValue=i.SessionValue from inserted i;    
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,SessionValue,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@empid,@empname,@SessionValue,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: Thank You For give me the ans for the same. 1 More Question is that In updateTrigger  how can I update table with session value and how can I fetch main table ID while update data ?

Comment: Same Code Goes For Updating Also Just Change  
FOR INSERT   to FOR UPDATE